# Windows8/win10 c++/c# :have multiple virtual desktop active at the same time

Tags: c#, c++, windows, remote-desktop, virtual-desktop

I'm developing a vr application for windows8/10 so that user can not only see and interact with the existing monitor plugged to their gpu in vr, but also create a new virtual monitor, or just open a application outside of the desktop/screen in vr space.

After some research, i figured i can show exising desktops on monitors by duplicatedesktop api, and also create/show/switch a virtual workspace, but how do i have multiple desktop object active at the same time with only one monitor?, so that my unity programming can create textures using duplicatedesktop api from those desktop object and show them in vr.

And also, is it possible to have a application window without/outside of a desktop?

My target is windows10, but would be best if also works on windows8 !, Thank you in advance!

And sry if my description sounds vague, im experienced in unity but just started on windows development.

Comment: From Aarin Michael Bailey: `What version and build of Windows?`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Mostly windows10, windows 8 is optional

Comment: update the *quewstion* with the relevant information. Most people won't read comments. If the question isn't clear they simply ignore it